# Class Cast Exception While Iterating List Returned From HQL

Tags: hibernate, hql

I am getting a ClassCastException when iterating a list retured from HQL

at this line

`UserPojo u=(UserPojo)userList.get(0);`

**UserDao.java**

```
public class UserDao
{
   Session session = null;
   Transaction tx=null;
   public int validateUser(UserManagedBean user)
   {
    int validateFlag=-1;
    try
    {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Query q = session.createQuery("select user1.userId, user1.userName, user1.password from UserPojo user1 where user1.userName=:userName and user1.password=:password");
        //Query q=session.getNamedQuery("validateUser");
        //Query q=session.getNamedQuery("proc_validateUser");
        q.setParameter("userName", user.getUserName());
        q.setParameter("password", user.getPassword());
        List<UserPojo> userList = q.list();
        //List<UserPojo> userList = (List<UserPojo>)q.list();
        int rowCount = userList.size();
        if (rowCount == 1)
        {
            UserPojo u=(UserPojo)userList.get(0);
            System.out.println("U.userId:"+u.getUserId());
            //user.setUserId(userList.get(0).getUserId());

            validateFlag = 1;
        }
        else if (rowCount == 0)
        {
            validateFlag = 0;
        }
        else if (rowCount > 1)
        {
            validateFlag = -1;
        }
        tx.commit();
    }
    catch (HibernateException e)
    {
        LOG.logp(Level.SEVERE, "UserDao", "validateUser", "Caught HibernateException During User Validity Check", e);
        try
        {
            tx.rollback();
        }
        catch(HibernateException ex)
        {
            LOG.logp(Level.SEVERE, "UserDao", "validateUser", "Caught HibernateException While Rolling Back Transaction", ex);
        }
    }
    return validateFlag;
 }
 public UserDao()
 {
     session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
 }
 private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(UserDao.class.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting 3 things in you query:

```
select user1.userId, user1.userName, user1.password...
```

Thus your query will return a `List<Object[]>` and not your `UserPojo`

Try something like this instead:

```
select user1  from UserPojo user1 where user1.userName=:userName and
user1.password=:password
```

**EDIT:**

So if you want your `List<Object[]>` to become a `List<UserPojo>` then you need to iterate through your `List<Object[]>` and assign UserPojo's fields manually.

`for(Object[] obj : list) {
    UserPojo userPojo = ...
    userPojo.setUserId(obj[0]);
    ...
}`

*Obs: I wouldn't use it like that, but that's up to you.*

Comment: I managed to get the user id with the same hql by making following changes to the code    `List<Object[]> userList = (List<Object[]>)q.list();` `Object [] obj=userList.get(0);` `                System.out.println("userId:"+obj[0]);`. Here entity was small so loading full of it is not an issue but in further development queries will become more long and loading the whole entity is not a good option.

Comment: Yeah, that was the first solution i figured out but using `from MappedPojo` will load data from all the columns 
(pls correct me if i am wrong), it's fine if table contains few columns. When we want to fetch only few columns (for eg from big table) instead of using `from MappedPojo`, u can put sql with selected columns into procedure and calling the procedure will return `List<MappedPojo>` and also it will set required(not all, as opposed to `from MappedPojo`) properties of the MappedPojo.Pls correct and suggest me some alternate way of fetching few columns from tables with too many columns.

Comment: I've found a answer to you in this link: http://goo.gl/SbzNrB I think what you need/want is what the user "baba" answered.

Answer (score 0):

Your query must be returning a `List<Object[]>` for all the fields you put in the `select` clause. I think using only the entity name in your `createQuery` should return a `List<UserPojo>`:

```
"select user1 from UserPojo user1 
    where user1.userName=:userName and user1.password=:password"
```

Comment: Thanks I understood what I ma doing